# Remote DataBase Access Any were over the internet

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, silverlight, connection-string

Suppose I have **two PC** both can be any were over the internet.
I required to access database of **PC1** through **PC2**.
Below screen shot of my IP Version Protocol Dialogue Box.

[image]

**NOTE:** PC1 is my PC where database should reside and PC2 will be any PC over the internet

I am using SilverLight For Developing WebSite\WebPage.
And for locally accessing database(MS SQL Server) I am using following connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SkiResultEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SkiResultModel.csdl|res://*/SkiResultModel.ssdl|res://*/SkiResultModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PRITESHARYAN-PC\PRITESHB_ARYAN;Initial Catalog=SkiResultData;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

What should be the modification I have to make in my connection string or in SQL Server Database Settings?
So Database in My PC that is **PC1** can be accessible from any were over the internet...
Please Help.....

Comment: You can't really do this, given your private, nat-protected ip block. You shouldn't want to, either. But assuming you want to anyway, you need to figure out your public ip (which might change) and use that, plus open the correct tcp/ip port through youtlr router/firewall. Still not recommended. Better option: web services.

Comment: any good example ...how to use webservices..?

Comment: @AndrewBarber actually i also doesn't know any thing about it...how to open tcp/ip port or etc also...

Comment: @AndrewBarber where is nat-protected ip block? thank you so much for replying

Comment: The fact that you have an ip address starting with 192.168.tells me you are using private addresses. These can not be used over the Internet. A firewall/router tutorial is off topic and far beyond the scope of an answer here. I recommend googling for some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using Silverlight, the remote PC will not access the database directly, but via your server that is running on PC1.

It is fairly complicated and involved. Steps:

- Set up IIS
- Deploy your Silverlight application to IIS (you need to change your connection string to use a username, password - not integrated security). Verify it works.
- Modify router to forward port 80 requests to 192.168.137.115:80
- Modify your PC firewall to enable inbound port 80 traffic
- Obtain your router's IP Address (use http://WhatsMyIpAddress.com )
- Verify port forwarding works by going to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx from the previous step.
- Provide the URL above to user on PC2 (note that some ISPs may change your IP address).

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Private_Network) between the two computers using [these instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-a-Vpn-Between-Two-Computers). I have not tried this and based on several online comments and questions, this gets difficult with different versions of Windows.